# Populate data from an API call in a drop-down with a corresponding account id

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am extracting data from the GTM API to google sheets.

I have successfully achieved the API call to fetch all GTM accounts belonging to the user (On the front-end & server side), however, **I am struggling with the API call to fetch a specific container for the selected account on the HTML side**.

**What I want to achieve**:

So when the user selects an account, I want to populate the container name for that particular account selected in a drop-down. I am not sure how to call this function `listContainers(accountId)` function and populate the drop-down.

**html**

```
//API call to fetch all GTM accounts belonging to the user

<div class="form-group">

     <label for="accountData">Select Account:</label>
          <select id="accountData" style="width: 100%">

 <? var data = listAccounts() ?>

<? for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) { ?>
    
    <option value="<?= data)[i].accountId ?>" ><?= data)[i].name ?></option>
   <? } ?>
</optgroup>
 
   
   </select>
</div>
```

**Code.gs**

```
//**Console.log**

[ { accountId: 'xxxxx', name: 'ABC' },
  { accountId: 'xxxx', name: 'CBA' }]

function listAccounts() {
  // API call to fetch all GTM accounts belonging to a user
  return TagManager.Accounts.list({
    fields: 'account(accountId,name)'
  }).account;
}

// API call to fetch specific container for an account



//**Console.log**
    [ { name: 'acb.net', containerId: 'XXXX' },
    { name: 'DEF', containerId: 'XXXX' } ]


function listContainers(accountId) {
  // API call to fetch all containers belonging to a specific GTM account
  return TagManager.Accounts.Containers.list(
    'accounts/' + accountId,
    {fields: 'container(name,publicId)'}
  ).container;
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `So when the user selects an account, I want to populate the container name for that particular account selected in a drop-down.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By the way, in your showing script, have you already confirmed that your functions `listAccounts()` and `listContainers(accountId)` correctly return your expected values?

Comment: Many thanks for responding. There are two drop down buttons on the HTML side: select account and select container. Select Account Dropdown is populated with ```listAccount()``` function and Select Container button should be populated with ```listContainers(accountId)``` function.  I want to pass account ID selected by the user to the second function i.e. ```listContainers(accountId)```. Both functions are working on the server side.

One GTM Account, can have several Web Containers. So, if I have the account ID, then I can pull the list of containers associated with that account id.

Comment: I have added the output above in my question for both the functions. @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have 2 dropdown lists. In your question, you didn't add the 2nd dropdown list.
- You want to set the values from `listAccounts()` to the 1st dropdown list.
- When the 1st dropdown list is selected, you want to set the values from `listContainers(accountId)` to the 2nd dropdown list.

#### Modification points:

- If your showing script and HTML are the actual situation, unfortunately, your HTML template is required to be modified. For example, those are `)` of `<?= data)[i].accountId ?>`, `<?= data)[i].name ?>`.
- In your Google Apps Script, I cannot know your script for loading the HTML template.
- From your reply, I understood that your functions of `listAccounts()` and `listContainers(accountId)` work fine.

From this situation, how about the following sample script?

#### HTML & Javascript side:

Please set your HTML template as follows. In this case, your Google Apps Script is not modified.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="accountData">Select Account:</label>
  <select id="accountData" style="width: 100%" onchange="select1(this)">
    <? var data = listAccounts() ?>
    <? for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) { ?>
    <option value="<?= data[i].accountId ?>" ><?= data[i].name ?></option>
    <? } ?>
  </select>

  <label for="accountData2">Select Account2:</label>
  <select id="accountData2" style="width: 100%" onchange="select2(this)"></select>
</div>

<script>
function select1(e) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(ar => {
    const select = document.getElementById("accountData2");
    select.innerHTML = "";
    if (ar.length == 0) return;
    ar.forEach(({name}) => {
      const option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = name;
      option.value = name;
      select.appendChild(option);
    });
  }).listContainers(e.value);
}

function select2(e) {
  alert(`${e.value} was selected.`);
}
</script>
```

- In this HTML & Javascript, when the HTML template is loaded, the 1st dropdown list is created by the value of `listAccounts()`. And, when a value is selected from the 1st dropdown list, the 2nd dropdown list is created by the selected value and the value of `listContainers(accountId)`.

#### Note:

- I cannot know your script for loading the HTML template. So, I suppose that your Google Apps Script works fine. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: @Arif Ahmed Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.